# Аналог position absolutе в android cardview

Tags: android, recyclerview, cardview

У меня есть на экране `recyclerView` который состоит из `cardview`. Вот как выглядит кусок:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот разметка одного элемента:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_border"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="70dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0.03dp">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/card_border">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgActivity"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="TODO" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

я не знаю как положить надпись над кружком. В веб-дизайне есть такая функция `position absolute` и у меня вопрос - есть такой аналог в андроид либо какой-то другой способ чтобы выглядело так как я хочу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Абсолютное позиционирование задеприкейтили уже много лет назад в Андроид.
Прочтите что-нибудь о `layouts` в UI Андроид, это важная тема для разработчика.

По теме. Если посмотрите в документацию
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView

`android.support.v7.widget.CardView` это потомок `android.widget.FrameLayout`, соответственно все приемы распределения элементов в `FrameLayout` работают и в `CardView`
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.LayoutParams

В вашем случае `android:layout_margin*` в сочетании с `android:layout_gravity` помогут достичь результата.

**Второй вариант.** Наверное, более правильный.
Возьмите вертикальный `LinearLayout`, поместите в него картинку и надпись, а сам контейнер вставьте по центру в `CardView`.

Comment: сейчас обновлю разметку в вопросе, может это поможет в решении проблемы

Comment: я решил закинуть все в framelayout, может если все элементы будут в нем то будет проще реализовать то что я хочу

Comment: Плохая идея. Вы засунули FrameLayout в FrameLayout. Какой в этом смысл? вертикальный LinearLayout там должен быть.

Comment: так тогда все сбивается в кучу

Comment: Тогда задайте новый вопрос, вам помогут.

Comment: а этот типа все? или может удалить его? как посоветуете? потому-что я думал что будет проще почему-то это сделать)

Comment: Вы же хотели ответ "есть такой аналог в андроид либо какой-то другой способ чтобы выглядело так как я хочу", я вам ответил. Вопрос закрыт. Не получается, задайте новый. Вопросы лучше дополнять, а не модифицировать. Теряется смысл для остальных, кто позже будет решать подобную проблему. SO это база знаний, а не бесплатная школа программирования.

Comment: я решил свою проблему, в моем новом вопросе есть решение, не факт что оно на 100% правильное но мне помогло. Буду рад если вы его посмотрите и скажите свое мнение - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/888880/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC-android. Спасибо что помогли в решении этой проблемы :)