# Расположение одного виджета над другим android

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-layout, cardview

У меня есть подобный вопрос - [Аналог position absolutе в android cardview](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/888855/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-position-absolut%D0%B5-%D0%B2-android-cardview) где благодаря ответу я почти нашел решение для своей проблемы. Теперь у меня мой список из карточек выглядит подобным образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

это означает что подпись элемента находится под карточкой, то есть это почти то что мне нужно только наоборот. Вот мой новый код разметки:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_border">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="70dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="0.03dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/card_border"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgActivity"
                android:layout_width="85dp"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:contentDescription="TODO" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</FrameLayout>
```

идея была взята с этого [сайта](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2rdtw6/cardview_overlapping_other_views/). И теперь собственно вопрос - как мне сделать все наоборот, чтобы моя надпись висела над карточкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что же вы разметку как пазл складываете, рандомно проверяя подойдет или нет.

Вот ваше решение. Осталось только сам `CardView` настроить.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/card_border"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="70dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0.03dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgActivity"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:contentDescription="TODO" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: что вы имеете в виду под настройкой cardView?

Comment: Переставьте местами ImageView и TextView если наоборот надо

Comment: его атрибуты, они зависят от того, куда вы его вставляете.

Comment: а мой framelayout тогда получается не нужен?

Comment: CardView и есть FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю верное ли это решение, но мне помогло. Нужно в моей разметке поставить в `cardView` `elevation` отрицательное и тогда карточка будет под надписью. Не уверен что это кому-то кроме меня поможет, но надеюсь что кому-то пригодится.